# How to clear all the values that selected in the react-select select component by using a function

Tags: reactjs, react-select

`<Select isSearchable disabled={!isEdit} className='customSelect' name='services' onChange={handleServices} isMulti options={options} isRequired={!isEdit} />`

I need to clear all the values that selected in a react-select select component when click on a clear button.
This the code snippet , I tried to clear with the inbuld handleChange function, but that was not working. The value is still there in the component

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://react-select.com/home) for this component show an "x" icon that can be used to clear the input. Assuming that you want to use a different button though, here is what I'd do. Just give the select an `id` and then clear the value of the select using the `id` on a button click:

```
<Select 
  // Other props...
  id="mySelect"
  isMulti
  options={options}
/>
```

Some button used to clear the select with a handler:

```
<button onClick={handleClear}>
  Clear the Select
</button>

const handleClear = () => {
  document.getElementById("mySelect")?.value = "";
}
```